# How do I update a google calendar event using Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I'm following the google calendar documentation to update an event via a service account [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update). Unfortunately, besides describing the initial setup with node in mind (which still doesn't show the process via a service account) google doesn't seem to include the node flavor in any further documentation.

My authentication is setup below:

```
//import google library
const {google} = require("googleapis")
//setup scope of auth
const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'];
//load client secrets from a local file
let credentialsRaw = fs.readFileSync(process.env.GOOGLE_CALENDAR_SECRET);
//get credentials as json parsed from raw file contents
let credentials = JSON.parse(credentialsRaw);
//setup auth obj
let auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    credentials.client_email, null,
    credentials.private_key, scopes
);
```

Followed by my code that tries to update the event:

```
//setup calendar object
const calendar = await google.calendar({
    version: "v3",
    auth
});

//make call to update calendar event
let updateResults = await calendar.events.update({
    auth: auth,
    calendarId: req.body.calendar_id, //log looks like: i798978asdfjka678sagsdfv3344@group.calendar.google.com
    eventId: req.body.event_id, //log looks like: 12432dsfkjhhwqejhkj12
    resource: {
        "summary": "Test Summary",
        "description": "Test Description",
        "end": req.body.end_time,  //log for end and start look like: { dateTime: '2021-08-09T11:30:00-04:00', timeZone: 'America/New_York' }
        "start": req.body.start_time,
    }
});
```

The error I get is "Not found". That's it. I've tried encoding the calendarId with `encodeURIComponent()` according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250769/the-api-returned-an-error-error-not-found-google-calendar-with-node-js) answer but that didn't change anything. The poster of that answer also mentioned later that the encoding fix isn't needed anymore.

Some common issues on the account side I think I've handled correctly:

- The project that the service account is in has the calendar api enabled
- The service account has domain wide authority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should show you how to authorize the service account.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: '/path/to/your-secret-key.json',
  scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events'],
});

const service = google.calendar({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: auth 
});
```

For more info see [service-account-credentials](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#service-account-credentials)

> Not found

Error normally means that you do not have access to the calendar you are trying to access. I would check to be sure the delegation was setup properly to the calendar.  Try testing with a calendar.get to be sure you have access.

Comment: It looks like my method of authentication worked but I hadn't shared the correct calendars with my service account. I thought domain wide authority accomplished that but I was wrong. Thank you for explaining the error message!